# Сервлет на java

Tags: java, netbeans, сервлеты

Есть сервлет на java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class CurrentDate extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String title = "Display Current Date & Time";
      Date date = new Date();
      String docType =
      "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
      "transitional//en\">\n";
      out.println(docType +
        "<html>\n" +
        "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
        "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
        "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
        "<h2 align=\"center\">" + date.toString() + "</h2>\n" +
        "</body></html>");
  }
}
```

При запуске в браузере отображается страница index.jsp, а не результат работы сервлета. IDE Netbeans 8.2. В более старых версиях Netbeans такой проблемы не было, насколько я помню.

web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CurrentDate</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>CurrentDate.CurrentDate</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CurrentDate</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CurrentDate</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: как запускаете, на каком сервере, что в web.xml?

Comment: Запускаю на Tomcat 8. В web.xml пакет и сервлет прописаны. Текст web.xml добавил в пост

Comment: Ну так сервлет ловит (url-pattern) /CurrentDate а не корень сайта.
Нужно или обращатся по урлу http://server/CurrentDate или написать что-то типа

    `<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>CurrentDate</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>`

Answer (score 0):

Не разу не видел чтоб при запуске веб приложения запускался какой либо Servlet. по умолчанию запускается всегда Index.jsp или .html 
Но все же есть вариант указать в **WEB.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>nameServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>nameServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup> // Тут указывается порядок запуска
</servlet>
```

Вызывает `init()` метод сервлета.

Comment: А как тогда запустить Index.jsp и получить при первом запуске данные из БД (речь о том как отработать сервлет) что бы вставить их в view?

Answer (score 0):

Вы отправляете html страницу. Поэтому не выполняется. Инициализируйте диспетчер сервлетов. + суффикс и префикс укажите. потом отправляется сервлет.